# Laptop turns on and off by itself

Tags: laptop, bios

Laptop: HP ProBook 4520s

I got my motherboard replaced. They tested in the repair service and everything was fine. I got the laptop home and it worked. Then I hibernated it and when I wanted to turn it back on - didn't load even the BIOS - just started turning itself off and on again in a time span of 2-3 seconds. I hear the usual "start up" sounds of the hardware. But the screen doesn't even get signal - I mean, even the background lighting up (even if still black) doesn't turn on.

I found many problems like that on the net, saying that the BIOS must be corrupted, but how come it was working and suddenly out of nothing it got corrupted?! And the solutions I found were by removing the RTC battery, etc.

I removed the battery and unplugged the power cable, even removed the RTC battery (so the BIOS resets to default) for quite some time, but the problem still persists.

Any ideas of what might be the problem?

Comment: @Syspect | I know you mentioned a BIOS issue, but just to eliminate a couple things, do you get the same issue if you boot from a live CD?

Comment: If its just come back from replacement, I would contact them...it doesn't look like its fully fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Although this appears to be a different resolution it may still resolve your issue.

```
Recovering the BIOS using key press combination
When you upgrade the BIOS on your notebook, a copy of the previous BIOS version is stored in the HP TOOLS partition of your hard drive. Many HP notebook computers have an emergency BIOS recovery feature that allows you to recover and install the last known good version of the BIOS from the hard drive, as long as the hard drive remains functional. This emergency recovery feature is separate from the BIOS and is designed to work in the event of a catastrophic BIOS failure.
To recover an earlier version of the BIOS on your notebook:

    Turn off the computer.
    Plug the notebook into power using the power adapter.
    Press and hold the Windows key and the B key down at the same time while the computer is off.
    Still pressing those keys, press and hold down the Power button on the notebook for 1 second, and then release the Power button and the Windows and B keys.
    The Power LED light remains on, and the screen remains blank for about 40 seconds before anything appears on the display. You might also hear beeping sounds. Eventually, an HP BIOS Update screen displays and the BIOS update begins automatically.
```

OR

```
To recover the BIOS on your notebook using the USB key:

Plug the notebook into an AC adapter.
Insert the USB key with HP_Tools installed into an available USB port.
Press the Power button while holding the Windows key and the B key.
The emergency recovery feature replaces the BIOS with the version on the USB key. The computer reboots automatically when the process is completed successfully.
```

Please note, the link below (the source) also gives much more detail including what happens if the above doesn't work!

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=uk&lc=en&docname=c02693833

Comment: yeah, nothing of the document worked... I will probably bring it to a service for diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (an HP ProBook 4540s), there was something wrong with the display assembly or the cable that goes from the motherboard to the display.

I got lucky and happened to get the laptop to work with the display at a certain angle (I could see Windows booting, etc.) but as soon as I moved the display, off she went.

I thoroughly inspected the cable because there seemed to be some wear in the area between the base and the display but all of the wires seemed okay so I ended up ordering another display assembly including the cable from eBay for $40 and viola! The laptop has worked flawlessly ever since.